# Strapi Api doens't show me content of my post when using Components and DynamicZones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, strapi

As the title says, my local Strapi project doesn't show the content of the post in API. Permissions are granted, I tried several times deleting and starting from scratch.

[As you can see, I have access to a single post "/api/post-templates/1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HantN.png)

[and I have access to several posts if I had them. "/api/post-templates"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64a8l.png)

The issue is, I can't see any content of the post fields I entered.

[Here is the example of the content type which gives its content and this content type is made by explicitly telling what I want on the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K5hB.png)

[Picture of Strapi-side which doesn't show its content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49xQF.png)

[And which shows its content in API.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyGTl.png)

I want to access content to use it on the front-end as I did in postCards case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on their youtube channel - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOSh2nogROg. if you want to see dynamic zones or components content in API you have to add "populate=*"  like this,   "/api/post-templates?populate= * "

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).